# python nested for loop is iterate only once

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

i created a program to compare two text file , and identify duplicate and unique items
but first for loop is running only once after that it exit without iterating second item in the file. if any one can help please do.

```
f1 = open("file1.txt","r")
f2 = open("file2.txt","r")

duplicate = open("duplicate_ip.txt", "w")
unique = open("unique_ip.txt", "w")

for x in f1:

    for y in f2:
        if x == y:
            duplicate.write(y)
        else:

            unique.write(x)
```

file1.txt contains following

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.10.2
192.168.56.5
192.16.10.2
192.168.5.5
```

file2.txt contain following

```
192.168.1.2
10.10.10.0
10.10.10.11
192.168.11.111
127.0.0.1
172.16.31.5
```

Comment: you only opened file.. but did not read it

Comment: The file referenced by `f2` is exhausted after the first run of `for y in f2`.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani Of course the file is read. Maybe you're not aware of it, but a file is irerable. With `for x in f1` you get every line in `f1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want f1 and f2 to be list of strings, then please use `readlines()` method. Also don't forget to close files (at least the ones you write to).

```
f1 = open("file1.txt", "r").readlines()
f2 = open("file2.txt", "r").readlines()

duplicate = open("duplicate_ip.txt", "w")
unique = open("unique_ip.txt", "w")

for x in f1:

    for y in f2:
        if x == y:
            duplicate.write(y)
        else:

            unique.write(x)
f1.close()
f2.close()
duplicate.close()
unique.close()
```

But there is a much simple way to manage file IO sessions with use of context manager. Your code will then will be looking something like this

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as f1, \
        open("file2.txt", "r") as f2, \
        open("duplicate_ip.txt", "w") as duplicate, \
        open("unique_ip.txt", "w") as unique:
    f1_lines = f1.readlines()
    f2_lines = f2.readlines()
    for x in f1_lines:

        for y in f2_lines:
            if x == y:
                duplicate.write(y)
            else:

                unique.write(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, you're opening the file, but not reading the lines, so you're not actually iterating over the file.

Couple comments:

- you should try to open files using `with` so you don't accidentily leave them open
- this still wont work, as the last line won't have a \n so you should probably remove them using `.replace`
- you're only checking one way, any ips in file2 that aren't in file 1 wont be found this way, not sure if that's what you want
- there are faster ways to check which items are the same in two lists and which are unique

To solve the main issue:

```
with open("file1.txt","r") as f1:
    data1 = f1.readlines()

with open("file2.txt","r") as f2:
    data2 = f2.readlines()

with open("duplicate_ip.txt", "w") as duplicate,  \ 
     open("unique_ip.txt", "w") as unique:
        
        for x in data1:
        
            for y in data2:
                if x == y:
                    duplicate.write(y)
                else:
        
                    unique.write(x)
```

Comment: you can avoid using nested context managers by separating them with comma)

Comment: that will fail, use backslash after `duplicate, `)

Answer (score 1):

Solution with set operation & (intersection) and ^ (XOR operation)

```
f1_ip = set(open("file1.txt","r"))
f2_ip = set(open("file2.txt","r"))

with open("duplicate_ip.txt", "w") as duplicate:
    for ip in f1_ip & f2_ip:
        duplicate.write(ip)

with open("unique_ip.txt", "w") as unique:
    for ip in f1_ip ^ f2_ip:
        unique.write(ip)
```

Comment: Note the order will be lost here - not sure if that matters

Comment: @Holloway Sure. If author need to save order then he can make set and write to file like ```if in unique then unique_f.write(ip) else duplicate_f.write(ip)```. In answer only idea for filter.

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this:

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as f1:
    data1 = set()
    for line in f1.readlines():
        data1.add(line.strip('\n'))

with open("file2.txt", "r") as f2:
    data2 = set()
    for line in f2.readlines():
        data2.add(line.strip('\n'))

unique_list = data1.difference(data2)
duplicate_list = data1.intersection(data2)

with open("duplicate_ip.txt", "w") as duplicate:
    for ip in duplicate_list:
        duplicate.write(ip+ "\n")

with open("unique_ip.txt", "w") as unique:
    for ip in unique_list:
        unique.write(ip+ "\n")
```